# I think I accidentally wiped out my ssd while installing Ubuntu

Tags: uefi, data-recovery, ssd, bios, data-loss

Today I was trying to install Ubuntu and dual boot with my already installed windows 10.
I downloaded Ubuntu's latest stable version and burned it to a flash disk. I chose the language then I saw this message

> The machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using BIOS compatibility mode.If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>   If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing system, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.

Then there were 2 options (**go back** or **continue to UEFI mode**). I clicked **continue to UEFI**. 
Then I chose **Something else**. After that I accidentally clicked on "revert". After I clicked the bar on the top turned green and things look like this.

[image]

Now I can't boot to Windows. I also can't see my data from the Ubuntu. I used to see my data when I use the "try Ubuntu" before clicking on revert but now they are gone.

Is there is a way to get my partitions and data back? :'(

I am using a Dell xps 15 laptop. 512 GB ssd. I had 2 partitions + windows (450MB I think system partition).

Before trying to install Ubuntu I disabled fast boot and secure boot. I use UEFI and AHCI mode.

Here is my RESULTS file from the boot info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24149512/

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @waltinator I successfully set up an EFI dual boot and I didn't read any of those things.  I just asked a couple of questions here.  Doesn't mean it's not a good idea though.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from an Ubuntu live disk boot. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith
Thank you.
Here is the link of my RESULTS.txt file "http://paste.ubuntu.com/24149512/"

Comment: Can anyone please explain to me what I did wrong? Even if I will not be able to recover the partitions I want to know what I did wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [Installation guide](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/02/manual-advanced-partitioning-in-ubuntu.html) it does not seem like changes are made at this step and thus clicking on revert will only undo the changes that you have done on that step of installation. It seems you can safely go back and mount the partitions and check if the data is intact(which it should be).

[This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147550) might tell you why you are facing this problem and maybe what to do next

If just in case if it isn't then [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a good package for file recovery(use the photorec package). But I have to warn you the files are not arranged on recovery and it's a cumbersome task.

Comment: The OP says his system won't boot.  That sorta sounds like changes were made.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147550 going by this, it seems that the erasing might have something to do with corrupted partition table or fakeraid meta data present on disk, which I have to say I do not understand correctly

Comment: Am I allowed to post a link to another forum in an answer?

Comment: @akabhirav 
I see links to external web pages on ask Ubuntu all the time. I think it's perfectly ok.

Comment: Testdisk used in the RIGHT way may help to copy out of a deleted/corrupted partition all the files organizzed in directoryes...good luck

Comment: @AndreaSimonetti .. Thank you I will search for it. can you recommend a tutorial of how to use it or something helpful?

Comment: Can anyone please explain to me what I did wrong? Even if I will not be able to recover the partitions I want to know what I did wrong!!

Comment: It is not easy to hunderstand what you did precisely.. But it is easy to mess up with windows new partitoning system.. If you want to try testdisk you don't have to try to rebuild the windows partitions but just make a deep search of the old partition.. After a double deep search you shall be able to print the files inside and then copy them to another disk..

Comment: @AndreaSimonetti .. I don't know how to do so. Can you explain more with steps please?. I am new to Linux. This was my first installation although I have great experience with win OS and networks. I want to learn Linux so I thought starting with Ubuntu is the best way to do so.

Comment: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step      This seems to be a good how to from the wiki. You can install it while you are running the ubuntu live from the usb.

Comment: Once you find the right partition listing the file inside you can copy what you need to a different disk.

Answer (score 0):

The description of what you did doesn't sound like it should have wiped Windows; however, it looks like that may have been what happened. Some key pieces of information:

- The GParted screen shot you showed reveals just three partitions on `/dev/nvme0n1`, which seems to be your SSD:

  - A 536 MB NTFS partition (too small for a full Windows installation)
  - A 511 MB partition of unknown type
  - A 511,060 MB partition of unknown type.
- The Boot Info Script output doesn't provide detailed partition information because it doesn't yet support NVMe devices; but it does provide three extra important details:

  - The NTFS partition's name is `Recovery`
  - The third partition is a Linux LVM partition
  - The LVM partition contains two logical partitions, `vg-root` and `vg-swap_1`. Thus, this partition has been written to, overwriting at least some data that used to be in whatever partition(s) it's replaced.

Overall, it looks like you've accidentally deleted your Windows installation and replaced it with a Linux LVM partition. If so, it's very unlikely that you'll be able to recover your Windows installation 100% intact; however, you should be able to use a tool like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover most of your individual files. Note, however, that PhotoRec reportedly does a poor job of recovering filenames, so figuring out what the files are will be a *very* tedious process. I've seen claims that some more Windows-centric tools do a better job of this, but I have no specific recommendations, except to ask about this on a Windows forum. If you have a recent backup, that may be a better way to recover. There's also a very slim chance that [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or a similar tool could recover your Windows installation. (You'll need to delete that LVM partition first, but *do not* write any data to it or create a new partition using GParted or other conventional partitioning tools.) If you try TestDisk and it works, be sure to run a disk check on the disk in Windows afterwards, since there may be filesystem damage. Even if there's no filesystem damage, it's possible that a few individual files will be damaged. There'll be no way to spot this except by checking each file individually.

When you re-install your system, you may want to consider the difference between native EFI/UEFI-mode booting and emulated BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting. BIOS-mode booting is more familiar to most people, but your firmware appears to be an EFI, not a BIOS, so booting in BIOS mode greatly complicates matters, as described [on this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) Installing both your OSes in EFI mode is likely to be preferable, even if you need to learn some new things to get it working optimally. Note, however, that this boot mode issue isn't really at the heart of your problem, despite the warning you received. My hunch is that you accidentally went too far in the disk-partitioning step and wiped out your Windows system by accident, which you could have done no matter which boot mode you'd used.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But what I did wrong!! 
Even if I will not be able to recover my partitions at least I want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't see any GParted screenshot. This looks like Ubiquity installer...

Comment: As I said, your description sounds like you did nothing wrong. There are a number of possible explanations: (1) You're misreporting (and possibly misremembering) something; (2) I'm misinterpreting something; or (3) you've encountered a bug. Short of reproducing the problem in a controlled environment, some uncertainty is inevitable in cases like this. Andrius: You're right; it's a Ubiquity partitioner screen shot; I misidentified it as GParted in my answer. That's an unimportant detail, though.